# How to get a decimal string from a Double instead of scientific notation in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, number-formatting

I need to divide a list of numbers by 100 to be printed, for example:

```
map (/100) [29, 3, 12]
```

produces:

```
[0.29,3.0e-2,0.12]
```

however I need:

```
[0.29,0.03,0.12]
```

How do I do this in Haskell? Any ideas really appreciated.

Comment: 3.0e-2 is equivalent to 0.03. They are the same number. Are you talking about PRINTING these numbers or something else entirely?

Comment: I know 3.0e-2 is equivalent to 0.03, I need the more usual form for printing. (Whenever I ask a question I get marked down, have I upset someone?)

Comment: That's a formatting issue (and handled by `Text.Printf.printf`). Concerning your question's score: the title and the contents don't match at all. A better title would be "how to show decimals with a certain format" or "how to avoid scientific notation in decimal output".

Comment: Thanks Zeta, I have now changed it.

Comment: "because 3 divided by a power of 10 can't be represented " But 3 / 10 produces 0.3.

Comment: @JulesMazur: Err, `0.0625` can be represented accurately (it's 2^{-4}), but still gets shown as `6.25e-2`. It's just that the `Show` instance for `Double` will switch to scientific mode whenever the first digit after the separator is zero.

Comment: @Zeta My mistake, then.

Comment: @IanStewart: It doesn't. Try `(3 / 10) * 100000000000000000000000` and be amazed.

Answer (score 14):

`0.03` and `3.0e-2` are the same number. Internally, GHC uses [`showFloat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:showFloat) to print it, which will result in the scientific notation whenever the absolute value is outside the range 0.1 and 9,999,999.

Therfore, you have to print the values yourself, for example with [`printf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#v:printf) from `Text.Printf` or [`showFFloat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:showFFloat) from `Numeric`:

```
import Numeric

showFullPrecision :: Double -> String
showFullPrecision x = showFFloat Nothing x ""

main = putStrLn (showFullPrecision 0.03)
```

Depending on your desired output, you need to write some more functions.

Answer (score 3):

What works for me is:
cabal install numbers and then in GHCi

```
λ: import Data.Number.CReal
λ: map (/(100 :: CReal)) [29,3,12]
[0.29,0.03,0.12]
```

Comment: That's just using a different, generally impractical,  numeric type with a different `Show` instance.

Comment: but it solves e.g. [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59664682/weird-behavior-of-(^)-in-haskell).

Comment: @WillNess, yes, but that's a thoroughly unrelated problem!

Comment: @dfeuer the original question has no constraints other than "to avoid scientific notation in decimal output"

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all your comments, now I understand the problem I don't mind using workarounds. The code was to find the lengths of sections of music based on the time each section begins - in the form of 1.28 for 1 minute 28 seconds. Now the result is a list with the timings as strings but that is not a problem. For anyone who is interested, here is the function with the workaround:

```
subtractMinutes :: RealFrac a => [a] -> [[Char]]
subtractMinutes (x:xs) = take (length (xs)) (zz : subtractMinutes xs)
    where ya = (head(xs) - x) * 100
          ys = truncate (head(xs)) - truncate(x)
          yz = ya - (fromIntegral(ys) * 40)
          yx = round(yz)
          za = div yx 60
          zs = mod yx 60
          zz = show(za) ++ "." ++ zx
          zx = if zs < 10 then "0" ++ show(zs) else show(zs)
```

Comment: Why `take (length (xs))`? This will drop the last element.

Comment: Hi Zeta, the music I am working on at the moment has 4 sections starting at  0.00 - 1.12 - 2.38 - 3.40 and ending at 5.28 (minutes.seconds) which produces ["1.12","1.26","1.02","1.48"]. There are 5 elements necessary in the function for the 4 sections.