# Haskell third argument of showFFloat

Tags: function, haskell

I was looking into some way to suppress scientific notation(a struggle every programmer has to deal with at some point) and I found this question:

[Haskell - how to avoid scientific notation in decimal output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006362/haskell-how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-in-decimal-output/37009015)

Now, the first answer uses something like this:

```
showFullPrecision x = showFFloat Nothing x ""
```

This works but I cant figure out what the last argument is and I dont want to just use code blindly.

The documentation for `showFFloat` says its signature is `showFFloat :: RealFloat a => Maybe Int -> a -> ShowS`. Taking in a `Maybe Int` and most likely a float, but what is up with the last argument(in our case an empty string)?

Comment: BTW, if you want something more flexible that `showFFloat`, I'd suggest the [number-show library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/number-show-0.1.0.0/docs/Text-Show-Number.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ShowS` has nothing to do at all with number-showing specifically, this is just the normal result of show-like functions. Morally, `ShowS` is just a string. The reason to use instead

```
type ShowS = String -> String
```

is that `String` has bad performance for concatenation, in particular, if you do something like

```
s0, s1, s2, s3, s4 :: String

   (((s0 ++ s1) ++ s2) ++ s3) ++ s4
```

then every `++` operator needs to traverse *all* the already-concatenated strings on its left, giving quadratic time complexity – very slow!

OTOH, with

```
(s0++), (s1++), (s2++), (s3++), (s4++) :: ShowS

   ((((s0++) . (s1++)) . (s2++)) . (s3++)) . (s4++)
```

the runtime just composes together the functions, which is constant cost. To actually evaluate the concatenation, you'll end up with applying this chain to, as in your example, the empty string:

```
   ( ((((s0++) . (s1++)) . (s2++)) . (s3++)) . (s4++) ) ""
  = s0++(s1++(s2++(s3++(s4++""))))
  = s0++s1++s2++s3++s4
```

Therefore, functions that produce a string which is likely still going to combined with other strings preferrably yield such *difference-list* strings, instead of `String` directly. But if you just want to *view* such a shown string, what you need to do is always apply it to `""`.

Comment: Thank you! Sooo ShowS is... basically an internally represented string-thing, that can be applied to an empty string `""`, just like a function, to get the underlying `String`? Also, What happens if you apply it to a non-empty string?

Comment: If you apply it to some nonempty string you'll just get that string back, appended to the show result.