# Weird behavior of (^) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, floating-point, ghc, ghci

Why does GHCi give incorrect answer below?

GHCi

```
λ> ((-20.24373193905347)^12)^2 - ((-20.24373193905347)^24)
4.503599627370496e15
```

Python3

```
>>> ((-20.24373193905347)**12)**2 - ((-20.24373193905347)**24)
0.0
```

**UPDATE**
I would implement Haskell's (^) function as follows.

```
powerXY :: Double -> Int -> Double
powerXY x 0 = 1
powerXY x y
    | y < 0 = powerXY (1/x) (-y)
    | otherwise = 
        let z = powerXY x (y `div` 2)
        in  if odd y then z*z*x else z*z

main = do 
    let x = -20.24373193905347
    print $ powerXY (powerXY x 12) 2 - powerXY x 24 -- 0
    print $ ((x^12)^2) - (x ^ 24) -- 4.503599627370496e15
```

Although my version doesn't appear any more correct than the one provided below by @WillemVanOnsem, it strangely gives the correct answer for this particular case at least.

Python is similar.

```
def pw(x, y):
    if y < 0:
        return pw(1/x, -y)
    if y == 0:
        return 1
    z = pw(x, y//2)
    if y % 2 == 1:
        return z*z*x
    else:
        return z*z

# prints 0.0
print(pw(pw(-20.24373193905347, 12), 2) - pw(-20.24373193905347, 24))
```

Comment: This is an error w.r.t the mantissa. `a^24` is approximately `2.2437e31`, and thus there is a rounding error that produces this.

Comment: I don't understand. Why is there a rounding error in GHCi?

Comment: this has nothing to do with ghci, it is simply how the floating point unit handles floats.

Comment: That computes `2.243746917640863e31 - 2.2437469176408626e31` which has a small rounding error which gets amplified. Looks like a cancellation issue.

Comment: Why don't I see this behavior in Python?

Comment: Maybe python uses a different algorithm for exponentiation, which in this case is more precise? In general, no matter the language you use, floating point operations exhibit some rounding error. Still, it could be interesting to understand the differences between the two algorithms.

Comment: @Randomdude: because `(**)` calculates a "power" on the FPU unit, whereas `(^^)` uses an iterative algorithm. If you use `((-20.24373193905347)**12)**2 - ((-20.24373193905347)**24)` in Haskell you get `0.0` as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I actually checked that earlier, and it does not evaluate to zero.

Comment: @chi: locally it works, I use a 64-bit FPU.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah! I tried on another machine, and it did work. I was not expecting that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short answer**: there is a difference between [**`(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-94-) and  [**`(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42--42-).

The `(^)` function works only on integral exponents. It will normally make use of an iterative algorithm that will each time check if the power is divisible by two, and divide the power by two (and if non-divisible multiply the result with `x`). This thus means that for `12`, it will perform a total of *six* multiplications. If a multiplication has a certain rounding-off error, that error can "explode". As we can see in the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#%5E), the [`(^)` function is implemented as](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/libraries/base/GHC/Float.hs#L377-L396):

> ```
> (^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
> x0 ^ y0 | y0 < 0    = errorWithoutStackTrace "Negative exponent"
>         | y0 == 0   = 1
>         | otherwise = f x0 y0
>     where -- f : x0 ^ y0 = x ^ y
>           f x y | even y    = f (x * x) (y `quot` 2)
>                 | y == 1    = x
>                 | otherwise = g (x * x) (y `quot` 2) x         -- See Note [Half of y - 1]
>           -- g : x0 ^ y0 = (x ^ y) * z
>           g x y z | even y = g (x * x) (y `quot` 2) z
>                   | y == 1 = x * z
>                   | otherwise = g (x * x) (y `quot` 2) (x * z) -- See Note [Half of y - 1]
> ```

The `(**)` function is, at least for `Float`s and `Double`s implemented to work on the floating point unit. Indeed, if we take a look at the implementation of `(**)`, we see:

> ```
> instance Floating Float where
>     -- …
>     (**) x y = powerFloat x y
>     -- …
> ```

This thus redirect to the [**`powerFloat# :: Float# -> Float# -> Float#`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#v:powerFloat-35-) function, which will, normally be linked to the corresponding FPU operation(s) by the compiler.

If we use `(**)` instead, we obtain zero as well for a 64-bit floating point unit:

```
Prelude> (a**12)**2 - a**24
0.0
```

---

We can for example implement the iterative algorithm in Python:

```
def pw(x0, y0):
    if y0 < 0:
        raise Error()
    if y0 == 0:
        return 1
    return f(x0, y0)


def f(x, y):
    if (y % 2 == 0):
        return f(x*x, y//2)
    if y == 1:
        return x
    return g(x*x, y // 2, x)


def g(x, y, z):
    if (y % 2 == 0):
        return g(x*x, y//2, z)
    if y == 1:
        return x*z
    return g(x*x, y//2, x*z)
```

If we then perform the same operation, I get locally:

```
>>> pw(pw(-20.24373193905347, 12), 2) - pw(-20.24373193905347, 24)
4503599627370496.0
```

Which is the same value as what we get for `(^)` in GHCi.

Comment: The iterative algorithm for (^) when implemented in Python does not give this rounding error. Is (*) different in Haskell and Python?

Comment: @Randomdude: as far as I know, the `pow(..)` function in Python only has a certain algorithm for "int/long"s, not for floats. For floats, it will "fallback" on the power of the FPU.

Comment: I mean when I implement the power function myself using (*) in Python in the same way as Haskell's implementation of (^). I am not using `pow()` function.

Comment: @Randomdude: I've implemented the algorithm in Python, and obtained the same value as in ghc.

Comment: Updated my question with my versions of (^) in Haskell and Python. Thoughts please?

Comment: @Randomdude: if you calculate the difference between the "real" result, the error is higher: the difference with `pw(pw(-20.24373193905347, 12), 2) - (-20.24373193905347) ** 24` is `-2.7021597764222976e+16` for the power in the question, and `-1.8014398509481984e+16` for the algorithm in the answer. The idea is to use a second float to build up errors, since then the "virtual mantisse" is larger so to speak. But it thus results in slightly different results. Whereas the power function without that correction results in two values who are more far "off", but exactly the same amount off.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you!

Comment: The errors in multiplication do not “explode.” They accumulate gradually. Let em be the maximum relative error that can occur in a single correctly-rounded operation in round-to-nearest mode, which is ½ ULP. If we have two prior results with errors e1 and e2, that is, we have numbers x•(1+e1) and y•(1+e2) that are approximations of the ideal mathematical number x and y, then the floating-point result of multiplying them is x•y•(1+e1)•(1+e2)•(1+e0), where −em≤e0≤em. So the result is x•y•(1+(e0+e1+e2)+es), where es is some second-order value (around 2^-104 for the IEEE-7754 binary64 format).

Comment: In other words, each multiplication adds at most a tiny relative error. Where large relative errors arise is when you subtract two numbers of similar magnitude. It is subtraction removing the “bulk” of the number that results in large apparent errors, not multiplication.